# openDNS and proxy settings

Tags: proxy, opendns, web-filtering

My work PC is connected to my company domain and it uses proxy settings. I tried to block a site(eg. facebook.com) using openDNS settings, it did not work.

Will openDNS work if I use proxy settings ? Is there any workarounds ?